# How do I catch simple errors with Haskell's BSON module?

Tags: haskell, bson

I have a group of Data.BSON.Document structures that I am digging through, converting each one into a User data structure (I defined User).  The function to do the unpacking is pretty straightforward:

```
docToUser :: Document -> Either String User
docToUser u = do
    name <- look "name" u >>= \(String t) -> return $ unpack t
    email <- look "email" u >>= \(String t) -> return $ unpack t
    token <- look "auth" u >>= \(String t) -> return $ unpack t
    Right $ User name email token
```

The catch, though, is that it does not actually seem to error out in an Either context.  Here are some example runs:

```
*DB> docToUser ["name" =: "Savanni", "email" =: "savanni@nowhere.com", "auth" =: "random_token"]
Right (User {name = "Savanni", email = "savanni@nowhere.com", token = "random_token"})
*DB> docToUser ["name" =: "Savanni", "email" =: "savanni@nowhere.com", "a" =: "random_token"]
*** Exception: expected "auth" in [ name: "Savanni", email: "savanni@nowhere.com", a: "random_token"]
```

So, the first run returns a user wrapped inside a `Right` constructor.  The second one I expected something such as `Left "field not found"`, but instead get a full exception.  Why is this happening instead of an error stored within an Either data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information that I can find from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112212/is-there-no-standard-either-a-monad-instance), and general other googling around... the instance for the Either monad does not *have* a `fail` implementation.  On a guess, that would be why I get an exception instead of Left.  I wrote this little test to demonstrate:

```
eitherMonad :: String -> Either String String
eitherMonad val = do
    if val == "abcd"
        then fail "val is abcd"
        else return "val is something else"

*DB> eitherMonad "abcd"
*** Exception: val is abcd
*DB> eitherMonad "efgh"
Right "val is something else"
```

On the other hand, `fail :: String -> Maybe String` really does return Nothing.  It would appear that the correct way to do my docToUser conversion is something more akin to this:

```
docToUser :: Document -> Either String User
docToUser u = do
    let name  = look "name" u :: Maybe Value
    let email = look "email" u :: Maybe Value
    let token = look "auth" u :: Maybe Value
    case (name, email, token) of
        (Just (String n), Just (String e), Just (String t)) -> Right $ User (unpack n) (unpack e) (unpack t)
        (Nothing, _, _) -> Left "username not found"
        (Just (String n), Nothing, _) -> Left "email not found"
        (Just (String n), Just (String e), Nothing) -> Left "auth token not found"
        otherwise -> Left "Something else broke"
```

I would imagine that can take quite a bit of refinement, especially in detecting and reporting which fields failed.  But, this seems to be pretty close to the answer.

I think, given that, that this question is a duplicate of [Is there no standard (Either a) monad instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112212/is-there-no-standard-either-a-monad-instance)

Comment: Note you don't need to put the `Just (String ..)` lines in all the later cases, the `Nothing` in the earlier cases will catch them, i.e. `case .. of ... ; (Nothing, _, _) -> ...; (_, Nothing, _) -> ...; (_, _, Nothing) -> ...` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

`look` indicates “not found” throught the monadic `fail` primitive. The fact that your return type is `Either` is irrelevant. You cannot handle this failure within a `do` expression; you'll have to write something like this:

```
unpackUser u = case (look "name" u, look "email" u, look "auth") of
    (Just (String name), Just (String email), Just (String token)) -> Right $ User (unpack name) (unpack email) (unpack token)
    _ -> Left $ "Missing required fields"
```

Comment: The output is caused by a call to `error`, which is the same as `fail` in IO, but `fail = Left` in the Either monad.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Which monad `look` is in is unrelated to the use of `Either` by `unpackUser`. In my example, `look` uses `Maybe`. It could use `Either`, too.

Comment: The unpacking in the question is explicitly in the Either monad, so the `fail`ure should happen within it, I.e. Left rather than an exception.

Comment: Eh… what do you mean by unpacking?

`t` in the question is `UString`, which is `CompactString UTF8`, and `unpack` converts that to `String`.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/compact-string-fix/0.3.1/doc/html/Data-CompactString-UTF8.html#v:unpack

Comment: I renamed `unpackUser` to `docToUser` since that seemed to be causing some confusion.  Either way, I expect all of the `look` operations to happen in an `Either` context, which would mean that `fail = Left`.  If it is *not* happening in that context, I would like to know why and how to change it so that it does.  I can only figure some kind of error in the lines that do the look/unpack of each field.

Comment: If you want your `look` in the `Either` context: dammit, I can't enter formatted code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `look` in the `Either` context:

```
docToUser = do
    String name <- look "name" u
    String email <- look "email" u
    String token <- look "token" u
    return $ User (unpack name) (unpack email) (unpack token)
```