# Should I use Either monad or ErrorT monad trasformer?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, either

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112212/is-there-no-standard-either-a-monad-instance). Here is citation of accepted answer:

> This instance has been added in base 4.3.x.x, which comes with ghc 7. Meanwhile, you can use the `Either` instance directly, or, if you are using `Either` to represent something that may fail you should use `ErrorT` monad transformer.

I want to use `Either` for something like this:

```
> (Left "bad thing happened") >>= \x -> Right (x ++ " ...")
Left "bad thing happened"
```

So, if one part of the computation fails, its `Left` is returned.

Actual question is: why should I use `ErrorT` monad transformer instead of `Either` monad? I'm a novice in Haskell, and I'm kinda afraid of monad transformters, especially when I'm already writing code inside one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `Either` if it fits your case. An example of where it *wouldn't* be sufficient is if you want to perform some `IO` in the middle of your computation, e.g.:

```
x <- mightReturnLeft
y <- liftIO someIOAction
useXandY x y
```

In that case, `Either` isn't sufficient, but `ErrorT` would work.

Also, I'd recommend using [ExceptT](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/transformers-compat/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) instead of `ErrorT`. `ErrorT` relies on the `Error` class which makes it more awkard to use.

Comment: Well, in your example we have to use a monad transformer because IO monad is a one-way monad. Is there `EitherT` transformer? Does `ExceptT` work like `EitherT`?

Comment: My understanding is that ExceptT is an EitherT that is 'blessed' by being in transformers and mtl.  I don't know why EitherT is an outsider, but I like the name ExceptT better.

Comment: @Mark In practice I would probably end up using `EitherT` from [the either package](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/either/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html) since it's been around longer. The two are functionally equivalent. I referenced `ExceptT` in my answer since it also comes from `transformers`, and is what `ErrorT` has been deprecated in favor of.